# How can I get Median in SQL Server in a Group by statement?

Tags: sql-server

Note: This is NOT a repeat question

I have a specific need to have Median calculation within a GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT [Date]
    ,[Symbol]
    ,AVG(([LastAsk] - [LastBid])) AS [Spread]
FROM [DATA].[1M].[Eggs]
WHERE [LastBid] > 0
    AND [LastAsk] > 0
    AND [LastBid] < [LastAsk]
GROUP BY [Date]
    ,[Symbol]
```

How can I exchange the AVG in this statement with a MEDIAN?

Note my [Eggs] table has 60 million rows.

Comment: Do you want median for each group?

Comment: Yes, for each [Date],[Symbol] group

Comment: See also  https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median

Answer (score 0):

Using [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh231473(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Date]
    ,[Symbol]
    ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY  xxx) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date],[Symbol])
FROM [DATA].[1M].[Eggs]
WHERE [LastBid] > 0
    AND [LastAsk] > 0
    AND [LastBid] < [LastAsk]
```

Comment: what is xxx? I am intersted in ([LastAsk]-[LastBid])

Comment: A column you use to establish sorting.

Comment: I need the difference between 2 columns

Comment: @ManInMoon Provide sample data and desired resultset. Preferably using https://dbfiddle.uk